# how to disable minimum dates on datepicker dialouge fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, datepicker

i am using following code to show dialogefragment on xamarin.android i have 2 questions.

1. How can i set default seleted date as current date (currently it
   shows next month)?
2. How can i disable past dates on dialougefragment?

   ```
   new DatePickerFragment(delegate (DateTime time)
           {

           var _selectedDate = time;
           txtDateTime.Text = _selectedDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");

       }) .Show(FragmentManager, DatePickerFragment.TAG);
   ```

Comment: have you tried DateTime.Now for current date

Comment: where can i set this? in above code?

Comment: and for 2) dialog.DatePicker.MinDate = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
dialog is of type DatePickerDialog

Comment: var _selectedDate = time.Now ..try that

Comment: sir, there is no object of this dialouge. only using above code to show fragment, can you please elaborate in context of above code?

Comment: don't you have OnCreateDialog() ?

Comment: no there is no method like this. and i cant override

Comment: don't you have object of DatePickerDialog in your code, or there is some piece that I'm overlooking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i set default seleted date as current date (currently it shows next month)?

If you want to set default selected date as current date, you can set DatePickerDialog datetime.

```
DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity, this, currently.Year, currently.Month,
                                                       currently.Day);
dialog.DatePicker.DateTime = currently;
```

> How can i disable past dates on dialougefragment?

You can sets today's date as minimum date.

```
dialog.DatePicker.MinDate = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
```

Here is the DatePickerFragment.cs:

```
 public class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
{
    // TAG can be any string that you desire.
    public static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof (DatePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();
    Action<DateTime> _dateSelectedHandler = delegate { };

    public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        // Note: monthOfYear is a value between 0 and 11, not 1 and 12!
        DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
        Log.Debug(TAG, selectedDate.ToLongDateString());
        _dateSelectedHandler(selectedDate);
    }

    public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<DateTime> onDateSelected)
    {
        DatePickerFragment frag = new DatePickerFragment();
        frag._dateSelectedHandler = onDateSelected;
        return frag;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity, this, currently.Year, currently.Month,
                                                       currently.Day);
        dialog.DatePicker.DateTime = currently;


       dialog.DatePicker.MinDate = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
       
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    TextView _dateDisplay;
    Button _dateSelectButton;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _dateDisplay = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.date_display);
        _dateSelectButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.date_select_button);
        _dateSelectButton.Click += DateSelect_OnClick;
    }

    void DateSelect_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        DatePickerFragment frag = DatePickerFragment.NewInstance(delegate(DateTime time)
                                                                 {
                                                                    
                                                                     _dateDisplay.Text = time.ToLongDateString();
                                                                 });
        frag.Show(FragmentManager, DatePickerFragment.TAG);
    }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]